# How do I include strings from a non-tag field as tags using django-tagging?

Tags: python, django, django-tagging

In Django, using the django-tagging app, I want to make it so that items included in a field that isn't a TagField (e.g., `authors`, in this example) are added to the list of explicitly provided tags when the object is saved.

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    authors  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags     = TagField()
```

If the authors that are submitted are "John, Bob, Mary" and the tags "cooking, fun" are submitted, how do I get the final tag set to be "John, Bob, Mary, cooking, fun"?

I tried adding a custom save function to the Publication class, but I don't think I got it right.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Publication, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    for author in parse_tag_input(self.authors):
        Tag.objects.add_tag(self, slugify(author))
    super(Publication, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How do I add in those extra tags?

Answer (score 0):

I think second super(...).save(...) is wrong.
You doing all right according [docs](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/trunk/docs/overview.txt#383)